# 404 error after saving changes in WAS 7.0.0.43 admin console

Tags: websphere, windows-server-2012, websphere-7

I've installed WAS 7.0.0.43 on 2012 windows Server standard. When I change some settings in the admin console, specifically in data Source, after saving the changes i receive an 404 error. In logs i see the following:

> C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\config\cells\SW06000008114Node01Cell\nodes\SW06000008114Node01\resources.xml
> (Access is denied.)

What did I miss? And this error I've ever got only on 2012 servers.
I only can change the setting in config files, but i don't like this.

Comment: User that started server has read only permissions to `profiles\AppSrv01` folder. Fix that and restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm the permission of this file and its folder recursively: `C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\config\cells\SW06000008114Node01Cell\nodes\SW06000008114Node01\resources.xml`

The permission should be "Modify" to the User Owner of the WAS process running in the server, or the group of its user.